# Third party employment : Good or Bad

Tags: salary, new-job, consultants

I have been working on payrolls of an IT giant. But my growth has been stalled here. I have got offer for a job via third party. Though they are paying me more but I am sceptical about third party payrolls. I asked that consultant(third party) and he said there is no problem regarding job security. Any views about the following will be helpful.

- Is it ok to get employed via third party when your last two employments were on permanent company payrolls
- Are people recruited via third party paid less?

Comment: If you want to be employeed by a third-party ( not sure what you mean by this ) then you should do it.  You decide what is "ok" and "not ok" just understand any obligations that your decision creates.  People are paid less for a varity of reasons all unique to the indivual getting paid less.

Comment: It means pay will be processed by a third party .

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a poll on workplaces which is off topic per [help]

Comment: Hi cbinder. Welcome to The Workplace. Speculative questions aren't really what we do here; instead, we try to focus on questions that can be answered more objectively. Check out [help/on-topic] as well as [ask] for further guidance. If you can edit this (or any of your other closed questions) to meet those guidelines, they'll get bumped into our reopen review queue.  If you're new to our site, you might also take the [about]. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is it ok to get employed via third party when your last two
>   employments were on permanent company payrolls

Certainly, it's okay.

I assume here that you mean "will it look bad for future employers if I am now paid by a third party?" It's unlikely future employers will care one way or another.

> Are people recruited via third party paid less?

No. People are paid what they negotiate for - without regard to who is signing the check.